# Spring Security upgrade to 3.1.0.RELEASE - cannot find setContextClass to define what instance should be used to create a fresh SecurityContext

Tags: spring-security

The docs for *HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter* say the following

"If a valid SecurityContext cannot be obtained from the HttpSession for whatever reason, a fresh SecurityContext will be created and used instead. **The created object will be of the instance defined by the setContextClass(Class) method** (which defaults to SecurityContextImpl."

But it says "**Deprecated**. *Use SecurityContextPersistenceFilter instead*."

I have swapped over to *SecurityContextPersistenceFilter* but now I cannot figure out how to set the instance to our own implementation of SecurityContext.

I have spent all day searching but have had no luck. I hope its not a case of the answer staring me in the face! :/ Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring 3.2.4, `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` obtains `SecurityContext` like this:

```
SecurityContext contextBeforeChainExecution = repo.loadContext(holder);
```

The default `repo` is `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` that instantiates `SecurityContext` like this:

```
protected SecurityContext generateNewContext() {
    return SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
}
```

So, if you want your own strategy to generate a fresh `SecurityContext`, you could do the following:

1. Extend `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` (let's say you name it `MySecurityContextRepository`)
2. Override its `generateNewContext()` method
3. Inject `MySecurityContextRepository` into `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` instance via constructor parameter (as `setSecurityContextRepository()` setter is deprecated)